# Play sound on page flip in Android

Tags: android

I have an Aurdino Comic where there are so many Jpeg Images. I want to show this images with sound. Which means, when I flip the next page then a flipping sound will be played.

Is this possible? I am new to android, please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but it doesn't have anything to do with the image I guess. The function you use to flip to the next page can call a procedure to change the sound.

You can find more on playing sound [on the android media topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)

Comment: I have read Media topic But I am unable to search exact solutions

Comment: You have to read and understand it, not search for an exact solution to copy!

Comment: Well, your question was if it is possible. If you have a framework of code, but are unable to incorporate sound for some reason, you might be better of starting a question with your current code, and tell us where the problem is.

Comment: How to start what? Playing a sound? Calling a function when you flip the page? Making an android project? If you don't show us where you are, it's really hard to point you where to go. If you have nothing, you might want to start with the http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html tutorial?